# Qbject.Equal in Linq to Entity Where Statement Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to use `Object.Equal()` for query using an exsiting object.

For example 
Suppose that I have a class named `Term`.

I have created the below object.

```
var term = new Term() {Code = "Plant - weed variety" };
```

Also in the class term I have overriden `Equals` method to be as below:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return Equals(obj as Term);
}

private bool Equals(Term t)
{
    return t != null && t.Code == Code;
}
```

But when I execute the below piece of code it return null.

```
var dbTerm = context.Term.Where(t => t.Equals(term));
```

When I looked up SQL Profiler, I have found that the query executed at the SQL side is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP(1) [c].[pk], [c].[code], [c].[created_by], [c].[creation_date], [c].[description], [c].[hash_code], [c].[id], [c].[last_updated_by], [c].[last_updated_date], [c].[legacy_id_from_source], [c].[name], [c].[scope_pk], [c].[status_pk], [c].[vocabulary_pk]
FROM [term] AS [c]
WHERE @__term_0_Pk = [c].[pk]',N'@__term_0_Pk bigint',@__term_0_Pk=0
```

The question is: why the query is translated to be a where using `PK` instead of the code ?

Thanks

Comment: Because Entity Framework ignores your `Equals` for the purposes of SQL generation. You likely want to use `var code = term.Code; var dbTerm = context.Term.Where(t => t.Code == code);`

Comment: Just to add to @mjwills 's comment, it seems this behavior is going to change in EF7 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adonet/2014/10/27/ef7-v1-or-v7/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the query is translated to be a where using PK instead of the code ?

Entity Framework only knows that you're calling the object.Equals method inside the Where clause. Linq expressions do not offer any visibility into the actual implementation of a method that's called from inside it. When Entity Framework tries to convert that expression tree into a SQL query, it has to make an assumption about what is meant by a call to object.Equals, which it assumes is a primary key comparison.

You'll need to put how you're comparing the objects into the actual expression in the Where() call. I.E.

```
var dbTerm = context.Term.Where(t => t.Code == term.Code);
```